# Debug session was finished without being paused It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, valet

I'm trying to use xdebug with phpStorm, valet on macOs
I followed the instructions,
installed xdebug, added configurations and set the settings in phpStorm

xdebug config parameters:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

I keep getting this error message and xdebug doesn't breach at the break points:

> Debug session was finished without being paused
> It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
> To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'dashboard.test' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line
> in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
> Do not show again

this is my configuration details

[image: Server config]

[image: PHP debug config]

[image: DBGp settings]

[image: Path mapping config]

[image: php ini]

I tried many suggested solutions but none of them is working,

Update:
changed the host from https://dashboard.test into dashboard.test, the message disappeared but still can not step over or step into every line (break point)

[image: break points]

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Does "Break at first line" help?

Comment: As a starting point: `https://dashboard.test` is not a valid host name - `dashboard.test` is

Comment: I tried it but it breaks only at first line don't break on the break point I put

Comment: but this is the virtual host I use in the browser do I use localhost?

Comment: I'll try it dashboard.test

Comment: The input field is labeled  **host**, not **URL**

Comment: @NicoHaase now the message disappeared but I can not step over every line all break points color became green but no step into or step over are working

Comment: 1) Please remove "Use path mappings" checkbox in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers. Looks like you don't need it. 2) What happens when you step in/over? The screenshot you've attached looks fine. 3) Switch on "Debugger" tab on your last screenshot - would it show any errors/warnings?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitrii it works fine now after removing the checkbox use path mappings

Comment: Great, was happy to help